# Display data in JTextField from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I want code in swing that take value from JComboBox and display it in JTextField, and
setFocus to JTextField by checking the JCheckBox.
inititialy JTextField should be empty. when JCheckBox is checked dispaly the selected item from JComboBox in JTextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "ComboBox Example" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox( "Display Selecte Item" );
        final JTextField text = new JTextField( "" );
        text.setEditable( false );
        final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox( new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" } );
        checkBox.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JCheckBox check = ( JCheckBox ) e.getSource();
                if( check.isSelected() ) {
                    Object obj = combo.getSelectedItem();
                    text.setEditable( true );
                    text.requestFocus();
                    text.setText(  obj == null ? "No Item Selected" : obj.toString() );
                }
            }
        } );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3,2 ) );
        panel.add( new JLabel( " Select Item:" ) );
        panel.add( combo );
        panel.add( checkBox );
        panel.add( new JLabel( "" ) );
        panel.add( new JLabel( "Selected Item" ) );
        panel.add( text );

        frame.add( panel );
        frame.pack();;
        frame.setVisible( true);
    }

}
```